# SSH to AWS instance with pem key asks for password

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

I'm trying to ssh to AWS server with pem key provided by our client. 
I tried the command

```
ssh -i yrg-labour-uat-securelink.pem  ubuntu@uat04.yrgconnect.online -v
```

Then it asks me for the password while there is no password. I have no access to server so I can't follow instructions found on google. I've tried the command from windows commandline, ubuntu and debian terminals and gave permission 600 to pem key. But nothing works. The output is shown below.

```
ian@MYPC:~/04-securelink$ ssh -i my_key.pem  ubuntu@domain.name -v
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to domain.name [18.141.54.32] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file yrg-labour-uat-securelink.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file yrg-labour-uat-securelink.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version xxxxxxx
debug1: no match: xxxxxxx
debug1: Authenticating to uat04.yrgconnect.online:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<7680<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:2M8Zy2YoxfD47hglpTGMYRPX8F+4VKyA5MsFtbbgz18
debug1: Host 'domain.name' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ian/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
ubuntu@domain.name's password:
```

Please help me!!!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem is not on client or server machines. What's causing the problem is the firewall from our office wifi which restrict key exchange between client and server machines.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two reasons for this as I can think of

1. Maybe you are using the wrong user, check whether `ubuntu` is the right user
2. Maybe the server owner has enabled `PasswordAuthentication` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: I think ubuntu is the right user. But I tried other users like -  root, ec2-user and admin, those doesn't work too. Our client send me a video of him connection to the server with the same command and the same key, it works on his machine. So, I think , may be, the problem is on my local machine?

Comment: Maybe your client has IP table rules in place to allow access only from certain IPs

Comment: Thank you. I'll try asking him to check ip table.